# Set a circle label for a separate Cell of CollectionView [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, indexpath

I'm trying to draw a circle for a visible cell of CollectionView, look like this

[image]

I tried to make it trough `addSubview` and then `removeFromSuperview` the previous label, but it doesn't work

```
let myIndex1 = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    let myIndex2 = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)
if indexPath.row == 0 {

    collectionView.cellForItem(at:myIndex1)?.addSubview(labelNew)
            labelNew.layer.backgroundColor = selectedItem.title.cgColor

        }

        if indexPath.row == 1 {

            labelNew.removeFromSuperview()
            collectionView.cellForItem(at:myIndex2)?.addSubview(labelNew2)
            labelNew2.layer.backgroundColor = selectedItem.title.cgColor

        }
```

What is the right way to draw a circle around a cell of CollectionView which is in the centre at the moment?

Comment: Can you share any sample project?

Comment: @Dharmesh Yeah, for example, I'm using this project from Github https://github.com/rserentill/iOS-WheelMenu and I want to draw an additional circle around a visible cell. So you can see in this project that label changes every time when cell changes. I want to do the same for an additional circle which I'll draw around the cell. Like here https://ibb.co/L6nSxjb

Comment: So you are trying to achieve what is mentioned in your question with this https://github.com/rserentill/iOS-WheelMenu lib?

Comment: @Dharmesh  I'm using Github's project as a start project. I'm trying to achieve this https://ibb.co/L6nSxjb

Comment: Got it. let me check

Comment: I believe this circle view shouldn't belong to the collection view cell, but should be added as a subview to the collection view's superview as well. Then just set proper frame, so the circle matches desired position right above the cell.

Comment: Something like this: https://i.gyazo.com/1a13acb2e23b9c70df01af80f14687c3.gif?

Comment: @Dharmesh No, additional circle around of the previous cell must be removed when the next cell appears

Comment: ok that make sense.

Comment: Check this out: https://i.gyazo.com/0e7cef36687cbf61c8f3e13d7d988dfd.gif

Comment: @Dharmesh yes, I'm trying to do this

Comment: @Antonin Charvat I'm trying, but I can't calculate y-position of the background label for the cell. I've got this https://ibb.co/jTCpQvv

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192861/discussion-between-dharmesh-and-diana).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the [library](https://github.com/rserentill/iOS-WheelMenu) you are using. Add an background image in your cell which will be shown as same size as your `collectionView` and set it `hidden` by default. then you need to apply the logic in your `scrollViewDidScroll` method and show background image for cell which is in centre like:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: currentIndex, section: 0)
if let cell = wheelMenuCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? WheelMenuCollectionViewCell {
    cell.backImage.isHidden = false
}
```

And to remove previous cell background image you need to add

```
for (index, _) in items.enumerated() {
    if index != currentIndex {
        let oldIndexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
        if let cell = wheelMenuCollectionView.cellForItem(at: oldIndexPath) as? WheelMenuCollectionViewCell {
            cell.backImage.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

and your `scrollViewDidScroll` method will look like:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let maxOffset = scrollView.bounds.width - scrollView.contentSize.width
    let maxIndex = CGFloat(self.items.count - 1)
    let offsetIndex = maxOffset / maxIndex

    let currentIndex = Int(round(-scrollView.contentOffset.x / offsetIndex)).clamped(to: (0 ... self.items.count-1))

    if self.items[currentIndex].id != self.selectedItem.id {
        self.selectedItem = self.items[currentIndex]
    }

    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: currentIndex, section: 0)
    if let cell = wheelMenuCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? WheelMenuCollectionViewCell {
        cell.backImage.isHidden = false
    }

    for (index, _) in items.enumerated() {
        if index != currentIndex {
            let oldIndexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
            if let cell = wheelMenuCollectionView.cellForItem(at: oldIndexPath) as? WheelMenuCollectionViewCell {
                cell.backImage.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now to show first cell highlighted when user start the app you need to add

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
        if let cell = self.wheelMenuCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? WheelMenuCollectionViewCell {
            cell.backImage.isHidden = false
        }
    })
```

in your `viewWillAppear` method.

Check [THIS](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=09127333818303331653) sample project for more info.